# Multithreading in PHP for image conversion

Tags: php, multithreading

I'm converting lots of images in 3 formats.My images have around 5 MB in size. I am converting in Large medium and small but my program is taking too much time to execute. So is there any facilities in PHP where can I use Multithreading in my program?
And how can I implement it?

Comment: Have a look at forking: http://php.net/manual/de/function.pcntl-fork.php

Answer (score 0):

I use to create a lot of pdf's and print them, this line:

```
$command = ('/usr/bin/nohup /usr/bin/php /path/to/cli/file/print.php '  . $args . ' & echo $!');

$PID = shell_exec($command);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/recoilphp/recoil

You could send multiple asynchronous request using recoil. You would need PHP7 to use it. The readme supplies plenty information, so I refer you to it.